# How do I prove Minkowski's inequality from this version?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Rudin - RCA p.63

The text states the Minkowski's inequality as follows:

> Let $(X,\mathfrak{M},\mu)$ be a measure space and $f,g:X\rightarrow [0,\infty]$ be measurable functions.
>
> Then, for $1<p<\infty$, $(\int_X (f+g)^p d\mu)^{1/p}\leq (\int_X f^p d\mu)^{1/p} + (\int_X g^p d\mu)^{1/p}$.

And the author next says that in $L^p$ space ($1<p<\infty$), the inequality $||f+g||_p \leq ||f||_p + ||g||_p$ can be directly proven by Minkowski's inequality, but how so?

It can only be directly proven that $|||f|+|g|||_p \leq ||f||_p + ||g||_p$, where the left-hand-side term is not $||f+g||_p$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the triangle inequality 
$$ \def\a#1{\left|#1\right|}
\a{f+g} \le \a f + \a g $$
taking the $p$-th power and integrating gives 
$$  \def\n#1{\left\|#1\right\|} \n{f+g}_p^p \le \n{\a f + \a g}_p^p $$
Now use the inequality above.

Comment: Aha.. Right thank you

Answer (score 0):

you forgot that W. Rudin wrote: "Let $f$ and $g$ be measurable functions on $X,$ with range in $[0, \infty]$". Now, apply Martini.